# android studio - how to export from command line

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to export a project to zip file in `Android Studio` using windows `command` line?

Of course I know it can be done using android studio gui.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you have to use **[Gradle wrapper command line tool](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)**.

It's available as a batch file for Windows (gradlew.bat) and a shell script for Linux and Mac (gradlew.sh), and it's accessible from the root of each project you create with Android Studio.

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline).

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know there is no such command to export Android Project as Zip from Command line. You can export only from Android Studio by `File > Export to Zip File` which you already know.

Alternatively you can do it using gradle task. Create a gradle task and run that task from command line. 
Below is gradle task:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
   from projectDir
   exclude 'build'
}
```

**Note**: Here `build` is excluded. You can exclude other directories/files if you want.

Comment: @Shanthi did you see my answer?